How to use the output of github-script action in the next step
I'm using github-script action to detect the changed files in the current PR and then i want to use it in the next step to send the output to a python script
I have the following yml:
steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        
      - name: bbb
        id: bbb
        uses: actions/github-script@v7
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const response = await github.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/files', {
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              pull_number: context.payload.pull_request.number
            });
  
            const files = response.data.map(file => file.filename);
            console.log(`FILES=${files.join('\n')}` >> $GITHUB_ENV);g
      # - name: Set up Python
      #   uses: actions/setup-python@v2  
      - name: Execute Python script
        run: |
          echo "my ${{ steps.bbb.outputs.FILES }}"

I tried many variation but I'm unable to use it in next step "Execute Python script"

You're mixing up a few things:

Environment files come in two flavours: $GITHUB_OUTPUT for outputs, $GITHUB_ENV for environment variables (see Environment files)
github-script steps set the output implicitly via return values

Here's an example from the github-script README:
- uses: actions/github-script@v7
  id: set-result
  with:
    script: return "Hello!"
    result-encoding: string
- name: Get result
  run: echo "${{steps.set-result.outputs.result}}"

As an aside, if you wanted to set a multi-line value from a script, you'd have to use this syntax:
{
    echo "output<<EOF"
    echo "line 1"
    echo "line 2"
    echo "EOF"
} >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

as you can't directly write a multi-line string to an environment file (see Multiline strings).

i thought that $GITHUB_OUTPUT is the output for each step...for some reason i missed the documentation about the return value thanks that would do the job

@KaramJaber It is the env file when using run: steps, but github-script abstracts it away.
